# Windows 8.1 DISM error 0x800f0906

Tags: windows-8.1, dism

I've had some issues with my laptop recently. It would randomly freeze and become unresponsive, and now completely fails to load anything on Chrome (strangely, incognito mode still works). I ran SFC multiple times and it would state there were errors that it was unable to fix, tried running SFCFix with no success. Now SFC is coming back with no errors, but DISM is showing error 0x800f0906. I ran Tweaking Windows Repair and still nothing seems to have changed.

Any idea what might be causing the issue?

EDIT: Logs attached below

[DISM.log](https://ufile.io/fhroq4p9)

[CBS.log](https://ufile.io/t497n4dm)

Also, I ran chkdsk and it found 168KB in bad sectors.

Comment: Both SFC and DISM creates a log indicating what problems were encountered during the process

Comment: May be related to this old article, where a windows patch breaks this function, solution is to uninstall the patch.....https://www.computerworld.com/article/2926179/microsoft-confirms-patch-kb-3022345-breaks-sfc-scannow.html

Comment: 0x800f0906 generally means it cant find the installation files. Is the machine connected to the internet?

Comment: I've checked and KB3022345 isn't in my list of installed updates.

Comment: And yes, it is connected to the internet. Really not sure why Chrome isn't working but IE works fine.
I will post back with SFC and DISM logs shortly

Answer (score 0):

Since Google Chrome seems to be the main issue,

- [Save your Chrome profile](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/export-chrome-profile-79321.html) (),
- Uninstall Chrome,
- Reboot, to be sure all old files are deleted,
- Reinstall Chrome,
- Restore the old profile, as above.

You also *might* benefit from reinstalling Windows 8.1 using the [ISO from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO). However, with the "[end of [Windows 8.1] Mainstream Support on January 9, 2018, and end of Extended Support on January 10, 2023](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18581/lifecycle-faq-windows-products)," you might look into an alternative, currently supported, OS such as Windows 10 or Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (which claims support through 2028).

Comment: Tried that but doesn't seem to have made a difference. I think it might be something to do with Windows Update, I had a similar problem a few months ago and ended up having to do a complete clean install. I just tried to refresh from the installation disc and it said there was an error, and all my system restore points have gone. Looking it like it might be another clean install.

Comment: Well, @tabularasa1, you'll be starting with clean slate.